# Как узнать положение скролла определенного div'a?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть див `.search-users` с `overflow-auto` (скролл показывается, когда внутри больше пяти блоков).
Как с помощью js узнать, прокручен ли скролл этого дива до последнего внутреннего `div.search-block`?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.search-users').bind('scroll',chk_scroll);
});


function chk_scroll(e)
{
    var elem = $(e.currentTarget);
    if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) 
    {
       alert('Конец');
    }

}
```

```css
.search-users{
 height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.search-block{
  margin:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='search-users'>
  <div class='search-block'>
  Lorem ipsum – псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона.
  </div>
  <div class='search-block'>
  Lorem ipsum – псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона.
  </div>
  <div class='search-block'>
  Lorem ipsum – псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона.
  </div>
  <div class='search-block'>
  Lorem ipsum – псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона.
  </div>
  <div class='search-block'>
  Lorem ipsum – псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона.
  </div>
  <div class='search-block'>
  Lorem ipsum – псевдо-латинский текст, который используется для веб дизайна, типографии, оборудования, и распечатки вместо английского текста для того, чтобы сделать ударение не на содержание, а на элементы дизайна. Такой текст также называется как заполнитель. Это очень удобный инструмент для моделей (макетов). Он помогает выделить визуальные элементы в документе или презентации, например текст, шрифт или разметка. Lorem ipsum по большей части является элементом латинского текста классического автора и философа Цицерона.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, а как можно анбиндить скролл? чтоб оно перестало проверять положение

Comment: Нужно дать возможность отключения для посетителя сайта?

Comment: нет, мне просто нужно при определенных условиях сделать так чтоб биндер каждый раз не проверял позицию скролла, вообщем отключить функцию а потом опять забиндить

Comment: что то я вообще протупил, просто в коде bind нужно было заменить на unbind